# How Does WeChat Find People Around You?

Tags: android, wechat

im wondering how does WeChat's Shake works ? not matter of sensor, i mean how does it find people in a circle radius ? is it a modifie version of asmack which sends last known latitude,longitude with each ping? im currently using a modified version of asmack in favour of FileTransfer, i also have maps on my application, am i able to use it without too much effort? thanks alot

Comment: Reza: Please be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Speculation:**

They send your latitude & longitude to their server, which queries for other users in a specified radius and returns the results to your device.

Comment: This is an hypotesis. A good one.

Comment: oh..it works on bluestacks on my PC..where they can't get latitude and longitude...It is just hypothesis...isn't it?